# Need to detect when a button is pressed in an iframe, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have an iframe which loads a form into it, now when this form is submitted or the button is clicked, I need a JavaScript function on the parent window to run, this should run WHILST the form is being submitted as the PHP behind it takes some time.

I have read something about the parent window could detect when the iframe is reloaded by using the onLoad call, but that's pointless as I need the function to run whilst the PHP is being executed not after.

Any ideas? No jQuery! I want to know how to do this myself with no shortcuts or other peoples code.

**Edit:**
I know this is wrong, how would I get it working as I can't get my head around it, basically I want to use a callback to test if there a certain value returned, if not fetch the data again!

```
function upload_progress() {
    //Get http request object
    var http = getHTTPObject();
    var check_status;   

    check_status = function(callback) {
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                //Response
                this.callback(http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.open("GET", "http://localhost:1234/ppa/php/upload_progress.php", true);
        http.send();
    }

    var status = check_status(x);
    if (status != "true") {
        setTimeout(check_status,1000);  
    } else {
        alert(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: plus one for wanting to learn the language instead of seeking an easy way out

Comment: iframes are bad for so many reasons, this is one of them, you sure you really need an i frame?

Comment: if jQuery is a shortcut, what about php itself? or the webserver, or your own os?

Comment: I have got to use an iframe as I need to have 2 different PHP scripts running... although, now that you mention it I could simply use ajax...

Comment: php runs on the server not browser, i don't see what an iframe has to do with it

Comment: Basically I have a script that will move some files, whilst this script is running I need another script to check on it's progress. This wasn't working at the same time last time I tried.

Comment: the technique you are after is called **Polling** use to be js\jquery and now you can add WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can hack/XSS the other site's files to inject the JS, you will have a hard time.

Now if you legitimately need to communicate with the other page, and you either have control of the other page or can setup it to communicate with your server, you can use [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage)

Comment: Is the window.postMessage function native? Or is it additional classes or other peoples functions I have to use?

Comment: It is native.You can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) for usage